# Excel charts: Overlaying scatter plot with bar chart

Tags: excel, plot, charts, scatter

I'm trying to create a combined scatter plot and "bar chart" - the bars extend the full height of the chart, but their width varies (I have a table with the start and finish points on the x-axis).

Here is a mock-up:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7qQS.jpg

Do you think this is possible in Excel?  I have found some links on how to overlay multiple plot types, but none involving variable width shaded areas as seen in the example.

Would really appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've written a tutorial showing how to [Highlight Certain Time Periods in a Chart](http://peltiertech.com/highlight-certain-time-periods-in-a-chart/).

Comment: Thank you!  I found that helpful.